# What is the color-critical graph of $C_n \vee K_m$?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I got the following exam question for which I don't know how to interpret it. It seems quite unclear to me. I'm hoping someone more experienced with Graph Theory could help:

"What is the color-critical graph of $C_n \vee K_m$ for general $n, m \ge 2$?"

By "$C_n \vee K_m$", the join of the two graphs is meant, i.e. drawing $C_n$ and $K_m$ and then connecting all the nodes in $C_n$ to all the nodes in $K_m$.
I know what it means for a graph to be color-critical, but I have never heard of "the color-critical graph of [some graph]".

Thank you in advance for your help!
Even just hearing that this exercise is indeed a bit unclear, would be helpful.

Comment: This exercise is indeed a bit unclear, but I'm also concerned about the ethics of asking for help on an exam question.

Comment: The exam has already been written (by others) and was released for students to practice. I don't think it is unethical to ask. Normally, I would ask the professor what he meant by it, but this professor would never admit to having phrased this exercise task unclearly or even say what he meant by it. He is a very strange man.

Comment: Maybe "subgraph" is what was meant instead of "graph"?